# What is the difference between the Atlas path and the Explorer's path?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Early on in the game, you get a choice to follow the Atlas or to forge your own path as an explorer.

What are the differences between these two paths?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explorer path literally just allows you to explore. You have no goal or objective, just see what you can find.

The Atlas path involves finding ten Atlas Stations in the galaxy map. Any further discussion involves massive spoilers for the end of the game.

The 'Center of the Galaxy' path is literally just find the center of the galaxy.

This can be seen by finding Priest Entity Nada. He will give you three options for support:

- Request Aid for Exploration (The exploration path)
- Locate nearest Atlas Station (The Atlas Path)
- Locate nearest Black Hole (The Center of the Galaxy path)